# StringEscapeUtils unicode convert not working in JAVA

Tags: java

```
**jsp code** 

<%

    String str="&#2340;&#2369;&#2350;&#2381;&#2361;&#2366;&#2352;&#2366; &#2344;&#2366;&#2350; &#2325;&#2381;&#2351;&#2366; &#2361;&#2376;?";

     out.println("StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(sJava):\n" + StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str));
    %>
```

**same in java class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

String str="&#2340;&#2369;&#2350;&#2381;&#2361;&#2366;&#2352;&#2366; &#2344;&#2366;&#2350; &#2325;&#2381;&#2351;&#2366; &#2361;&#2376;?";

 System.out.println("StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(sJava):\n" + StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str));
}
```

in jsp its show me perfect output. which i need . but when u use same code in JAVA Class.its return same string .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava()` has nothing to do with HTML entities such as `&#2340;`. You need `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml()` to unescape them.

In case of JSP these entities are rendered as characters by your browser, but in HTML source generated by your JSP they're still escaped, because `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava()` works the same way in both cases.

Comment: problem solved. it was problem in commons-lang 3.3.1. when i use commons-lang 2.6. its works fine .